# Interpolation in Simulink[Matlab]

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've got three matrix which contain values of time and corresponding function. I need function values summed over time. Here is my data set(Data columns are marked with red):
[image]
As you see, columns have different time and function values, so I need to interpolate them first.  I tried this model, that had no effect: 
[image]

Will appreciate any help in solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to interpolate each of your three tabulated functions at a new set of time values, then compute a running sum for each of these functions (since you mention needing "function values summed over time"). I believe you will need two different types of blocks to accomplish this:

- A [**Lookup Table block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/f4-4889.html#f4-5701) will allow you to interpolate the values of your functions at different time points. This will replace the "Interp" block shown in your model above. There are a few different options here depending on how you want to initialize your table data in the model:

  1. If you have a set of data that will stay the same throughout your simulation, you can just hardcode this data into the **Table data** property of a block. In this case, you could use a [**Lookup Table block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/lookuptable.html), a more general [**Lookup Table (n-D) block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/lookuptablend.html), or an [**Interpolation Using Prelookup block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/interpolationusingprelookup.html) (in combination with a [**Prelookup block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/prelookup.html)).
  2. If you want to load your table data from the workspace during the simulation, you could use a [**Lookup Table Dynamic block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/lookuptabledynamic.html) or an [**Interpolation Using Prelookup block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/interpolationusingprelookup.html) with its **Source** property set to use an input port. In this case you would have to load your data using a [**From Workspace block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) (as you do above) and then make sure you format the table data properly for the interpolation block to use.
- A [**Cumulative Sum block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dspblks/ref/cumulativesum.html) will allow you to keep a running total of the values your functions create over time. If you want to look at the running total for each function individually, you will have to add one cumulative sum block to the output of each interpolation block, then send each of these to your scope. If you want to look at the running total for all the functions added together, then you can use a [**Sum block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/add.html) as you do above to add your three signals, then add a cumulative sum block to that output before sending it to your scope.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace the "from workspace" blocks with "constant" blocks.

Constant blocks allow you to set the value to anything that could be evaluated at the command prompt.  This includes vanilla numbers (1, 6, 100, 1e6), arrays (1:3, 1:2:11, zeros(23,1), ones(10,4)*6), and workspace variables (simin1, simin2).

"From workspace" blocks, on the other hand, read one element per execution from the variable.

It looks like you want all of the points to be passed into the interp function every execution. (Another way of wording this:  The "Pts" input to the interp block is a constant, the "in" port (time) is the only input that changes each execution.)

Comment: Thnx for response. So, I've got only first element of simin1 variable during running model?

Comment: If you use "from workspace" blocks you will have the first element for the first execution, the second element for the second execution, and so on.  This is what the "from workspace" block does.

From your usage, it appears to me that you want the entire table being input into the interp block.  You can't use "from workspace" if you want the entire table every execution. 

You should be using the "constant" block instead.

If you are having trouble understanding, try connecting a "display" block to both a "constant" block and a "from workspace" block.  I think you will see the problem then.

Comment: When I run model I always get one weird number in display, which shows simin1, this number isn't even in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "Lookup Table Dynamic" block in the Simulink > Lookup tables library instead of the interp block and separate the xdat (time t column) and ydat (values) each in a separate variable/constant.